# What if the function is identically zero on a line in Hadamard three-lines lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

The lemma states that log $M(x)$ is a convex function.
However, if $M(x)$ is zero at one of endpoints, the logarithm function is not even properly defined. 
Is this happening only in the trivial case where the original function $f$ is identically zero? 
I think that must be the case, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $L(x) = \log M(x)$ is convex on an open interval $(a,b)$ with $-\infty < a < b < \infty$, it can't have a limit of $-\infty$ as $x \to a+$ or $b-$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Why can't $L(x)$ have $-\infty$ at endpoints if it is convex on $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Spiche: The graph of a convex function lies *above* its tangent line at any point.

Comment: @MartinR: But $L(x)$ in question may not be differentiable, isn't it?

Comment: If $L(x)$ is convex on $(a,b)$, and $a < s < t < b$, then $L(x) \ge  \dfrac{t-x}{s-x} L(s) - \dfrac{t-s}{s-x}  L(t)$ for $a < x < s$.  Similarly in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is holomorphic in the annulus $A = \{ a < \vert z \vert < b \}$
and 
$$
 M(r) = \max \{  \vert f(z) \vert : \vert z \vert = r \}
$$ 
is zero for some $r \in (a, b)$ then it follows from the identity theorem
that $f$ is identically zero on $A$. Conversely, if $f$ is not
identically zero,
$$
 M(r) > 0 \text{ for } a < r < b 
$$
so that $\log M(r)$ is defined (and finite) for all $r$.

Comment: I can understand that log$M(r)$ is defined and finite for all $a<r<b$ (in the three-circles theorem).

Comment: What I don't really know is, that the three-lines lemma seems to state that log$M(x)$ is defined and finite at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Spiche: For $f(z) = z$ and $a=0, b=1$ the limit at $a=0$ is $- \infty$. That won't happen if $a > 0$ (which is what Robert said) because then you can compare $L(x)$ with the secant line through any two points on the graph. But the limit can always be $+\infty$